# How to store a specific value from array to database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**SOLVED**:
I'm not sure if this has already ask in here. I'm trying to store values that were taken from a form which has data in array..so here's the code below:

```
<?php

$number = 3;

for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
?>

<form>
<label>First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname[]"><br>
<label>Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="lastname[]"><br>
<label>Gender: </label>
<select name="gender[]">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select><br>
<?php
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="Store_to_db">
</form>
```

Here's my table in my db:

```
|--id--|--name--|--gender--|
```

Anyone could help me? Thank you in advance.

(Thank you so much Litux):
I got now the answer regarding problem above.

SOLUTION:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['Store_to_db'])){
     $fnames = $_GET['firstname'];
     $lnames = $_GET['lastname'];
     $gender = $_GET['gender'];

     function show_Name ($f, $l){
        return "{$f} {$l}";
     }

     $user = array_map('show_Name', $fnames, $lnames);

      for($i = 0; $i < count($gender); $i++){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id, name, gender) VALUES('', '$user[$i]','$gender[$i]')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
     }
    }
?>
```

Comment: First of all - you have 3 `<form>` tags and one `</form>`. This is invalid markup.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the pitfall here? Don't know how to read the posted data, can't you loop through array, don't you know how to write to DB, don't you know how to sanitize data? Basic answer will be to add path to script in form action and handle it there. But i feel it won't suit. Therefore to read php.net is the only advise that I can propose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<form>` tag above the for loop.
Then you'll be able to submit all data with the submit button.
The data structure you'll get will be something like this:

```
$_POST['firstname'][0] = X
           [1] = Y
           [2] = Z
```

And so on for the other values like lastname and gender.

In your php file you can write a loop to get the posted data and put them into the database.
something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; i < 3; $i++) {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
$gender = $_POST['gender'][$i];
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (name, gender) VALUES ('".$firstname." ".$lastname."', $gender);
RUN QUERY
}
```

This is just an example. You also have to look whether the posted data are empty or valid etc...